# How to extend this regex to match alternatives with grouping?

Tags: python, regex

```
([abc])md([1-9])
```

This pattern can match the string 'amd1', and get access to the matched 'a' and '1'. I also want to match another possibility, for example:

```
amx1
```

In this case, I still want to get the groups of 'a', plus 'x'. That is, I want to make these 2 parts in OR relation:

```
d([1-9]) 
([a-z]1)
```

It can be represented with two patterns:

```
([abc])md([1-9])
([abc])m([a-z]1)
```

How to combine these two into one patterns?

Comment: You said you wanted an `or`.  So why not use an `or`?

Comment: I mean '|' to represent 'or' in regex. Right?

Comment: See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##HYzLCsIwEEX3@YrZTQZaIbhSED8kZBFNq4HmwSSLVPrvMbq6cM7h5r2@Uzz37kNOXIGX19IEN7gBo9T28TQU5P1wUqv5YugYbP4YRYSiVC6j02hDUziNcQqNWBNDAR/h568CILOPVf6fT6uPzm6b5DZBIer9Cw).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ?| should be ?:, right? Also, where is the 'import regex'? should be 'import re'?

Comment: Use `pip install regex` and try [the demo code](https://tio.run/##HYzLCsIwEEX3@YrZTQZaIbhSED8kZBFNq4HmwSSLVPrvMbq6cM7h5r2@Uzz37kNOXIGX19IEN7gBo9T28TQU5P1wUqv5YugYbP4YRYSiVC6j02hDUziNcQqNWBNDAR/h568CILOPVf6fT6uPzm6b5DZBIer9Cw).

Comment: Could you please clarify if you need to keep the output structure the same or not. If you want to get a (list of) two item tuple(s), you need either to use my example, or the one posted now with some code changes on your part.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
([abc])m(d([1-9])|([a-z]1))
```

Comment: OK, patterns can be embedded.

Comment: @marlon, time learning the tech you want to use is an excellent investment.